# Healpy display grid and midpoints

Tags: healpy

Using `python healpy`, I want to display (and export) the healpix grids that are used for sky tessellation (at different levels). How do I do this? Ideally I need the midpoints, the vertices of the grids and the lines that connect them.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on it, there are more ways:

1) you can use the IDL library that has a funcion pix2vec_nest (and pix2vec_ring) than can optionally return the 4 vertices of the pixel in a vector(n,3,4).

2) you can use the java version where there is the method HealpixBase.boundaries

3) you can use the HEALPix_cxx library that have the T_Healpix_Base::boundaries that acts the same.

With the boundaries you can display the grid. Note that the last method is very nicely coded, and it is easy to understand and use in another program! It need just the pixel index and the output vector:

```
 template<typename I> void T_Healpix_Base<I>::boundaries(I pix, tsize step,
  vector<vec3> &out) const
  {
  out.resize(4*step);
  int ix, iy, face;
  pix2xyf(pix, ix, iy, face);
  double dc = 0.5 / nside_;
  double xc = (ix + 0.5)/nside_, yc = (iy + 0.5)/nside_;
  double d = 1.0/(step*nside_);
  for (tsize i=0; i<step; ++i)
    {
    double z, phi, sth;
    bool have_sth;
    xyf2loc(xc+dc-i*d, yc+dc, face, z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    out[i] = locToVec3(z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    xyf2loc(xc-dc, yc+dc-i*d, face, z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    out[i+step] = locToVec3(z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    xyf2loc(xc-dc+i*d, yc-dc, face, z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    out[i+2*step] = locToVec3(z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    xyf2loc(xc+dc, yc-dc+i*d, face, z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    out[i+3*step] = locToVec3(z, phi, sth, have_sth);
    }
  }
```